# Erro React Native ao executar o npx react-native run-android

Tags: react, react-native

Esse erro esta aparecendo para mim quando uso o comando `npx react-native run-android`, como eu posso solucionar isso?

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the 
  Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. 
  Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: Command failed: 
  gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running 
  '[node, C:\Users\italo\OneDrive\�?rea de Trabalho\react\app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu ambiente de desenvolvimento parece não estar setado corretamente, recomendo que siga esse guia https://react-native.rocketseat.dev/

Comment: Entao eu tentei seguir os passos porem da um erro para instalar o emulador acho  ----------Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors